# Fuzzy matching (e.g. Levenshtein) between items in list

Tags: dictionary, patternmatching

I'm looking for an equivalent of the [Fuzzy Lookup Add-In for Excel](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011), which unfortunately doesn't work on my dataset (yields error `Unable to set the numberformat property of the range class`).

What I need is to get a list of fuzzy matches, e.g. based on [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), based on a dictionary. E.g. I would like to match `Micael`, `Michael`, `Micheal`, `Michel`, `Miguel`, `Mikael` and `Mikal`. I already have the (non matched) list of names. What I need is a service to iterate over it.

It's OK if the service only combines single matches (e.g. `Michel` matches `Miguel`, `Miguel` matches `Michel` etc. etc.), but it would be even greater if it produced a collection of synonyms, where all the matching items were collected on a row or in an array.

It would also be good if it supported configurable tokenization, so that e.g. `Chr` was converted to `Kr` at a cost of 1 (rather than 2, which would be the default).

The end goal here is to populate the [Nickname search in SharePoint 2013](http://www.myfatblog.co.uk/index.php/2012/08/nickname-search-in-sharepoint-2013/) based on a local repository of names.

The service can run locally or online. If somebody knows how to get around the Excel bug, that would also solve the problem.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you need. Do you need a web-service (which is off-topic here), a library (Sharepoint is developed in C# AFAIK) or what exactly? Why not implement Levenshtein yourself? It's not so difficult. For the `Chr` to `Kr` conversion, you probably need a language specific distance algorithm like [SoundEx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) for English or [Cologne Phonetics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cologne_phonetics) for German. Looks like Chr/Kr is some Eastern Europe specific thing.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I guess I can do it in Python, which I have some experience with, but before I spent time on it I would make sure I didn't duplicate someone else's effort.

Comment: I just saw a tip about [OpenRefine](http://openrefine.org/) elsewhere. I'll check that out.